# Improve elements position

Tags: android, text, app, graphics

I'm designing an android app and the only elements I have are a text and two buttons, with a large white background. I would you set these elements to improve the user experience? This is what I've done, but I don't really like the text position:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you already have is good. Listing a few things that may help improve –

1. Align text to left, so that both text and buttons are aligned.
2. Increase whitespace around the content to make it look more centered.
3. Use text-link for the secondary CTA. This will improve focus on the primary and maintain content alignment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context like what devices and orientation this app is supposed to run on, I'd pick the safest option and have a known mobile pattern where all of your content is laid down from the top, starting with the image header.

What you have shown here is more like a website layout and that's not something people would expect when downloading & using your app.

[image: like this]